# Flask Installation - Error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I tried installing Flask on a virtual environment on my PC that has Linux Mint. Ended up with this error:

```
*error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/itsdangerous.py'
---------------------------------------------------------------------- Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cMPDih/itsdangerous/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-HIVrsp-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cMPDih/itsdangerous/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates, that you're not working in the virtual environment. You probably haven't activated it. You can easily test and activate it:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python # oops, no virtual environment
$ source /home/user/venv/bin/activate
$ which python
/home/user/venv/bin/python # correct
$ pip install flask
```

You need to do the activate every time. You may create a start-script, for example in bash to activate it when running a program:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/venv/bin/activate
python /home/user/venv/myproject/main.py
```

Comment: Just use virtualenvwrapper which can make your life better.